# What is the purpose of the @WebServiceClient annotation?

Tags: java, web-services

I'm having trouble finding documentation as to the purpose of this annotation from some generated Java classes.  It appears that when I comment this annotation out of the code the SoapController class runs fine and can interact with the server without issue.  Is there a reason for this line?  Is it okay for me to comment it out in production?

This actually stems from a larger issue where I have to "fail-over" the server the webservice we are connecting to is on.  If server 1 fails, I need the webservice to try to connect to server 2 and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This explains it all here. Seems more of an IDE thing.

http://www.coderanch.com/t/225027/Web-Services/java/WebService-WebServiceClient-Annotations